# why my web application is not working with RDS instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch

I have the instance of MySQL db in RDS AWS and in my java web application I changed all the url for the new instance of db connection since I didn't write it in property file, my WAR file is working with the news instance when I have deployed it on local tomcat but when I deployed it in Elastic Beanstalk Application, it is not working, do you know the reason?

Comment: Does the RDS DB Security Group allow the instances launched by Elastic Beanstalk to connect to the DB? By the way, saying that something "is not working" is not the best way to report a problem - it would be more helpful if you were to provide an error message or an error code or perhaps an indication that the DB connection was failing or something like that - without this info, we are left to guess what "not working" actually means..

Comment: the user email login (from a jsp page) will be checked in a servlet and then it should be redirected to another jsp page, but for now it only goes to servlet page and not to the main jsp page, the VPC ID of RDS and EC2 inastances are the same. the region of both is in the east 1d and 1 e.

Comment: Take your webapp/jsp out of the picture. Can you connect to the RDS DB from the relevant client (your servlet instance)? If you can, then the problem is in the configuration of your webapp. If you cannot, then the problem is in the connectivity between that client and the RDS DB (and that may be the client security group egress rules, it may be the RDS security group ingress rules, or it may be routing).